# How to tell which option user selected in Android runtime permission dialog?

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

I'm requesting the `CAMERA` permission at runtime, which triggers the below dialog. How do I know whether the user selected `While using the app`, `Only this time`, or `Don't allow`? Is there some sort of callback I can use?

[image]

Comment: You can certainly tell the difference between 'Don't allow' and the others, since that's the only one where your permission was denied.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but how do you tell apart the top two? Trying to differentiate them for analytics purposes.

Comment: No, you cant know what did they choose between `While using the app` and `Only this time`, you may only know it on the next time you request, by tracking with the previous result (you have to save it for the next time check)

Comment: That sucks, but good to know! I will try keeping track of the previous result in the code. Thanks!